# I want to remove sed calls and use perl/

Tags: perl, sed

I want remove control characters from a file.

I am opening a file reading line by line and then printing the output to new file.
I was processing it line by line with perl with something like:

```
$_ =~ s/[^!-~\s]//g;
```

The while file open and closes are in it and everything. The file gets processed etc.But the changes do not seem to make it to the $_.

I put something like this in the perl script

```
#first crack at making it an ascii file
`tr -cd '\11\12\15\40-\176' < $fullpath_filename > $fullpath_filename_temp`;
unlink $filename;
rename $filename_temp, $filename;
`sed -i 's/^M//g' $filename`;
`sed -i 's/^[[:space:]]*//;s/[[:space:]]*\$//' $filename`;
`sed -i '/^\$/d' $filename`;
```

Anyhow it seems silly to put the tr and sed lines in when I could do it with perl... right in the perl script... but for some reason I cannot make perl do it.

Could someone help point the way? How can I make the tr and sed lines work using perl?

Comment: Using `sed` and `tr` in `perl`? You should start running before Larry Wall hunts you down.

Comment: I think `s/^M//g` is a bug. It's deleting "M" if it's the first character of a line. You probably meant to remove carriage returns, which you can do by removing `\15` from the `tr`.

Comment: the s/^M/ works.. in the terminal I did control+v then M and the character ^M appears as the carriage return character. The sed is working. I just want it all in perl.

Comment: @shortbusforcode `^` is a regex meta character, it will not match carriage return. If this was not true, it would be impossible to write a regex to match a line beginning with capital M.

Comment: But, it does work.. you are right if I just used the ^ by itself.. but I am entering the control+v and then m... on a linux box. This method does not work on windows. The regular ^ and M will show up like regular text... and the ^M with the "control+v and m" thing will show up as a blue text in my vi... so I know it is not the regular characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while (<>) {
   chomp;
   tr/\11\12\15\40-\176//cd;
   s/^M//g;
   s/^\s*//;
   s/\s*\z//;
   print "$_\n" if length;
}
```

I think `s/^M//g` is a bug. It's deleting "M" if it's the first character of a line. You probably meant to remove carriage returns.

```
while (<>) {
   tr/\x09\x20-\x7E//cd;
   s/^\s*//;
   s/\s*\z//;
   print "$_\n" if length;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure why when I did it it did not work. I obviously did not thing wrong. I don't have my initial attempt to compare.

Comment: to remove carriage returns: `tr/\r//d`

Comment: @glenn jackman, Why would you do that rather than taking out the `\15` like I showed?

Comment: missed that. IMO, `\t\r\n ` is more readable than `\11\12\15\40`

Comment: Remove control characters with `s/[[:cntrl:]]//g`

Comment: Awesome guys.. thank you. I discovered the problem was not with the removal code I was using or the code you guys have given me.... it was how I was manipulating the files and your telling me that this was the right way lead me down a debugging path leading to the errror.